# File Upload size restriction in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress on ubuntu server where whenever I try to install new theme I receive the error for file upload restriction. I browsed through various portal to find that I have to modify the variable set for "upload_max_filesize". I modified the same but still helpless.

Can anyone provide any inputs regarding the same ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Be careful there are often 2 php.ini file. Make sure you change the one used by apache and not the one used by PHP CLI. Its probably in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

make the below changes in you php.ini fie,

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

also check,

```
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file paste this code.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size           128M
php_value upload_max_filesize     128M
php_value memory_limit            500M
</IfModule>
```

Change the file size as per your requiremnet.

This might work to your both site in local and in server too.